# Can I use angular material 2 with an angularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

I have an AngularJS app and I found that the mat-table in angular material 2 is really suitable for my need but I don't know how to integrate it or if I can to the app. Does anyone know if I can ? 
I'm currently using the https://material.angularjs.org library that doesn't offer a table display.
So my question is can I use the angular material 2 library with in the AngularJS application ? 
If not, does anyone know of a library that offers a component like mat-table ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's no official table component for AngularJS Material, there is an unofficial library that I think is what you're looking for: [`md-data-table`](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table)

Another way would be to use a native `<table>` with `ng-repeat` and apply Material styles via CSS.

You could also port the table component to AngularJS via Angular Elements, although it can be tricky. *(I haven't tried porting it...)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, md-data-table is in fact what I'm looking for :)